# Node-red is restarting itself randomly

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, node-red

I recently noticed my node-red was deploying itself a time or two throughout the day. Below is a section of the log during this restart time. Any idea what is causing these restarts? I believe the problem in this example began at 7:15 am. At 7:16 am a node I have set to notify me on deploy was triggered.

```
May  3 06:25:02 raspberrypi-home-interface liblogging-stdlog:  [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.24.0" x-pid="354" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] rsyslogd was HUPed
May  3 06:43:54 raspberrypi-home-interface systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt upgrade and clean activities...
May  3 06:43:56 raspberrypi-home-interface systemd[1]: Started Daily apt upgrade and clean activities
May  3 06:43:56 raspberrypi-home-interface systemd[1]: apt-daily-upgrade.timer: Adding 1min 52.535189s random time.
May  3 06:43:56 raspberrypi-home-interface systemd[1]: apt-daily-upgrade.timer: Adding 37min 2.552325s random time.
May  3 07:15:52 raspberrypi-home-interface Node-RED[11414]: 3 May 07:15:52 - [red] Uncaught Exception:
May  3 07:15:52 raspberrypi-home-interface Node-RED[11414]: 3 May 07:15:52 - TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined
May  3 07:15:52 raspberrypi-home-interface Node-RED[11414]:     at handleResponse (/home/pi/.node-red/node_modules/node-red-node-weather-underground/wunder.js:66:29)
May  3 07:15:52 raspberrypi-home-interface Node-RED[11414]:     at Wunderground. <anonymous> (/home/pi/.node-red/node_modules/node-red-node-weather-underground/wunder.js:52:28)
May  3 07:15:52 raspberrypi-home-interface Node-RED[11414]:     at Request._call back (/home/pi/.node-red/node_modules/wundergroundnode/lib/wundergroundnode.js:148:22)
May  3 07:15:52 raspberrypi-home-interface Node-RED[11414]:     at Request.self.callback (/home/pi/.node-red/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)    
May  3 07:15:52 raspberrypi-home-interface Node-RED[11414]:     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
May  3 07:15:52 raspberrypi-home-interface Node-RED[11414]:     at Request.emit(events.js:191:7)
May  3 07:15:52 raspberrypi-home-interface Node-RED[11414]:     at Request.<anonymous> (/home/pi/.node-red/node_modules/request/request.js:1163:10)
May  3 07:15:52 raspberrypi-home-interface Node-RED[11414]:     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
May  3 07:15:52 raspberrypi-home-interface Node-RED[11414]:     at Request.emit(events.js:188:7)
May  3 07:15:52 raspberrypi-home-interface Node-RED[11414]:     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/pi/.node-red/node_modules/request/request.js:1085:12)
May  3 07:15:52 raspberrypi-home-interface Node-RED[11414]:     at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:292:16)
May  3 07:15:52 raspberrypi-home-interface Node-RED[11414]:     at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
May  3 07:15:52 raspberrypi-home-interface Node-RED[11414]:     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
May  3 07:15:52 raspberrypi-home-interface Node-RED[11414]:     at endReadableNT(_stream_readable.js:974:12)
May  3 07:15:52 raspberrypi-home-interface Node-RED[11414]:     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
May  3 07:15:52 raspberrypi-home-interface Node-RED[11414]:     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
May  3 07:15:52 raspberrypi-home-interface systemd[1]: nodered.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May  3 07:15:52 raspberrypi-home-interface systemd[1]: nodered.service: Unit entered failed state.
May  3 07:15:52 raspberrypi-home-interface systemd[1]: nodered.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May  3 07:15:53 raspberrypi-home-interface systemd[1]: nodered.service: Servicehold-off time over, scheduling restart.
May  3 07:15:53 raspberrypi-home-interface systemd[1]: Stopped Node-RED graphical event wiring tool..
May  3 07:15:53 raspberrypi-home-interface systemd[1]: Started Node-RED graphical event wiring tool..
May  3 07:15:55 raspberrypi-home-interface Node-RED[23224]: 3 May 07:15:55 - [info]
May  3 07:15:55 raspberrypi-home-interface Node-RED[23224]: Welcome to Node-RED
May  3 07:15:55 raspberrypi-home-interface Node-RED[23224]: ===================
May  3 07:15:55 raspberrypi-home-interface Node-RED[23224]: 3 May 07:15:55 - [info] Node-RED version: v0.17.5
```

Comment: Please post the log here, not an image.

Comment: The image shows the bottom half of an uncaught error stack. we need to see the full stack to be able to suggest what is causing it.

Comment: Sorry about that! The format of coping directly from the log looked terrible which is why I used a picture, but I formatted it to be easy to read. I edited the post to include the entire log that cat /var/log/syslog
shows

Comment: This looks like a bug in the Weather Underground Node, might be worth checking if there is a newer version (last update was 4months ago)